# XAudio2 - Cracking output when using a dynamic buffer

Tags: c#, c++, audio, xaudio2

To provide a little bit of context. I am trying to output live audio from a camera in my c# application. After doing some research it seems pretty obvious to do it in a c++ managed dll. I chose the XAudio2 api because it should be pretty easy to implement and use with dynamic audio content.

So the idea is to create the XAudio device in c++ with an empty buffer and push in the audio from the c# code side. The audio chunks are pushed every 50ms because I want to keep the latency as small as possible.

```
// SampleRate = 44100; Channels = 2; BitPerSample = 16;
var blockAlign = (Channels * BitsPerSample) / 8;
var avgBytesPerSecond = SampleRate * blockAlign;
var avgBytesPerMillisecond = avgBytesPerSecond / 1000;
var bufferSize = avgBytesPerMillisecond * Time;
_sampleBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
```

Everytime the timer runs it gets the pointer of the audio buffer, reads the data from the audio, copies the data to the pointer and calls the PushAudio method.
I am also using a stopwatch to check how long the processing took and calculate the interval again for the timer to include the processing time.

```
private void PushAudioChunk(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    unsafe
    {
        _pushAudioStopWatch.Reset();
        _pushAudioStopWatch.Start();

        var audioBufferPtr = Output.AudioCapturerBuffer();
        FillBuffer(_sampleBuffer);
        Marshal.Copy(_sampleBuffer, 0, (IntPtr)audioBufferPtr, _sampleBuffer.Length);

        Output.PushAudio();

        _pushTimer.Interval = Time - _pushAudioStopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        _pushAudioStopWatch.Stop();
        DIX.Log.WriteLine("Push audio took: {0}ms", _pushAudioStopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);                
    }
}
```

This is the implementation of the c++ part.

Regarding to the documentation on msdn I created a XAudio2 device and added the MasterVoice and SourceVoice. The buffer is empty at first because the c# part is responsible to push in the audio data.

```
namespace Audio
{
    using namespace System;

    template <class T> void SafeRelease(T **ppT)
    {
        if (*ppT)
        {
            (*ppT)->Release();
            *ppT = NULL;
        }
    }

    WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE wFormat;

    XAUDIO2_BUFFER buffer = { 0 };

    IXAudio2* pXAudio2 = NULL;
    IXAudio2MasteringVoice* pMasterVoice = NULL;
    IXAudio2SourceVoice* pSourceVoice = NULL;           

    WaveOut::WaveOut(int bufferSize)
    {
        audioBuffer = new Byte[bufferSize];

        wFormat.Format.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;
        wFormat.Format.nChannels = 2;
        wFormat.Format.nSamplesPerSec = 44100;
        wFormat.Format.wBitsPerSample = 16;
        wFormat.Format.nBlockAlign = (wFormat.Format.nChannels * wFormat.Format.wBitsPerSample) / 8;
        wFormat.Format.nAvgBytesPerSec = wFormat.Format.nSamplesPerSec * wFormat.Format.nBlockAlign;
        wFormat.Format.cbSize = 0;
        wFormat.SubFormat = KSDATAFORMAT_SUBTYPE_PCM;

        HRESULT hr = XAudio2Create(&pXAudio2, 0, XAUDIO2_DEFAULT_PROCESSOR);

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = pXAudio2->CreateMasteringVoice(&pMasterVoice);
        }

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = pXAudio2->CreateSourceVoice(&pSourceVoice, (WAVEFORMATEX*)&wFormat,
                0, XAUDIO2_DEFAULT_FREQ_RATIO, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        }

        buffer.pAudioData = (BYTE*)audioBuffer;
        buffer.AudioBytes = bufferSize;
        buffer.Flags = 0;

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = pSourceVoice->Start(0);
        }
    }

    WaveOut::~WaveOut()
    {

    }

    WaveOut^ WaveOut::CreateWaveOut(int bufferSize)
    {
        return gcnew WaveOut(bufferSize);
    }

    uint8_t* WaveOut::AudioCapturerBuffer()
    {
        if (!audioBuffer)
        {
            throw gcnew Exception("Audio buffer is not initialized. Did you forget to set up the audio container?");
        }

        return (BYTE*)audioBuffer;
    }

    int WaveOut::PushAudio()
    {
        HRESULT hr = pSourceVoice->SubmitSourceBuffer(&buffer);

        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            return -1;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is that I always have some cracking in the output. I tried to increase the interval of the timer or increased the buffer size a bit. Everytime the same result.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

I created 3 buffers the XAudio engine can go through. The cracking got away. The missing part now is to fill the buffers at the right time from the c# part to avoid buffers with the same data.

```
void Render(void* param)
{
    std::vector<byte> audioBuffers[BUFFER_COUNT];
    size_t currentBuffer = 0;

    // Get the current state of the source voice
    while (BackgroundThreadRunning && pSourceVoice)
    {
        if (pSourceVoice)
        {
            pSourceVoice->GetState(&state);
        }

        while (state.BuffersQueued < BUFFER_COUNT)
        {
            std::vector<byte> resultData;
            resultData.resize(DATA_SIZE);
            CopyMemory(&resultData[0], pAudioBuffer, DATA_SIZE);

            // Retreive the next buffer to stream from MF Music Streamer
            audioBuffers[currentBuffer] = resultData;

            // Submit the new buffer
            XAUDIO2_BUFFER buf = { 0 };
            buf.AudioBytes = static_cast<UINT32>(audioBuffers[currentBuffer].size());
            buf.pAudioData = &audioBuffers[currentBuffer][0];

            pSourceVoice->SubmitSourceBuffer(&buf);

            // Advance the buffer index
            currentBuffer = ++currentBuffer % BUFFER_COUNT;

            // Get the updated state
            pSourceVoice->GetState(&state);
        }

        Sleep(30);
    }
}
```

Comment: wild stab in the dark - have you tried nulling out the buffer?

Comment: Hello. No I haven't. How should I do that? Before I push the new audio chunk?

Comment: After you define it just set each byte to 0

Comment: Ok, Tried it but the same effect. Could it be that I override the the buffer before the XAudio device is finished with playing the whole buffer? Do I maybe need 2 buffers? A push buffer and a playback buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XAudio2 does *not* copy the source data buffer at the time you submit it via `SubmitSourceBuffer`. You must keep that data (which is in your application memory) valid, and the buffer allocated for the entire time that XAudio2 will need to read out of it to process the data. This is done for efficiency to avoid the need for an extra copy, but puts the multi-threaded burden of keeping the memory available until it's done playing on you. That also means you can't modify the playing buffer.

Your current code is just reusing the same buffer which is causing the popping as you change the data while it's play. You can solve this with having 2 or three buffers you rotate between. A XAudio2 Source Voice has status information you can use to determine when it's done playing a buffer, or you can register for explicit callbacks which tell you when the buffer is no longer being used.

> See [DirectX Tool Kit for Audio](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Audio) and [classic XAudio2 samples](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples/tree/master/XAudio2) for examples of using XAudio2.

Comment: Thank you for this info! I implemented this kind of solution last friday and it go better. I update my question above so you can have a look if I maybe did something wrong.